# quartz2.3 shutdown tomcat8 but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak

Tags: memory-leaks, quartz-scheduler

```
error:org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader clearReferencesThreads
serious: The web application appears to have started a thread named [QuartzScheduler_Worker-1] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak.

org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader clearReferencesThreads
serious: The web application appears to have started a thread named [QuartzScheduler_Worker-2] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak.
```

I am not been able to understand the cause of this problem. Can someone suggest me how to resolve this issue? thanks.

Comment: Can you please show us how you start the Quartz context (as instance, your web.xml configuration) ?

Answer (score 0):

Most likely that you didn't call shutdown() method on your scheduler